# How to resolve the Following Error.?

Tags: plutus

```
Command failed: transaction build  Error:
The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 1 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
Caused by: [ (force (builtin headList)) (con list (data) []) ]
Script debugging logs:
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you ended up calling `head` on an empty list `[]`? That can not work as there is no element to take from an empty list. `head` only works on lists with at least one element, and fails for the empty list.